# como diminuir o tempo de resposta de uma Web API?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Sou iniciante em C# e estou desenvolvendo um CRUD utilizando Angular e Web Api (Entity Framework Core), porém o tempo de resposta para listar os dados do meu ServersController na minha tabela é muito alto. O que acontece atualmente é que ele demora muito para listar apenas 48 registros (mais de 5 minutos ou as vezes nem carrega), conversando com um colega me foi proposto fazer a consulta no banco direto no meu método Get e consumir a consulta por ali mesmo, a grande questão é: como eu posso consumir esta consulta? pois a conexão/instância do banco eu consegui fazer. Segue o código atual abaixo:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Server>>> GetServer()
  {
     using (var context = new ITControlContext())
     {
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT e.Name [Environment], t.Name [ServerType], p.Name [Plant] FROM [ITControl].[dbo].[Server] s INNER JOIN [ITControl].[dbo].[Environment] e on s.IdEnvironment = e.IdEnvironment INNER JOIN [ITControl].[dbo].[ServerType] t on s.IdServerType = t.IdServerType INNER JOIN [ITControl].[dbo].[Plant] p on s.IdPlant = p.IdPlant";
            context.Database.OpenConnection();
            System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
     }

       return await _context.Server.Include(i => i.IdEnvironmentNavigation).Include(i => i.IdServerTypeNavigation).Include(i => i.IdPlantNavigation).ToListAsync();
  }
```

O que eu tentei fazer foi criar uma "nova instancia" do meu banco e fazer a consulta lá mesmo (eu não sei muito o que eu fiz) e gostaria de retornar os dados dessa consulta para poder listar eles na minha tabela sem demorar tanto. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer ou me dar algum Norte do que pesquisar/estudar?

Ps: eu imagino que eu tenha que alterar algo no meu `return`

Comment: pq tem um select pra um DataTable e depois outro no Entity ?  ainda assim teria que ver como está seu banco, e qual ponto exatamente está havendo a demora

Comment: o do Entity eu deixei pq é o que eu estava usando antes do colega me falar pra fazer a consulta no Get mesmo, segue link como esta no meu [banco](https://prnt.sc/tttj7x)

Comment: comenta o bloco using todo...deixa só a linha do entity... ainda assim há demora ? aí só vendo o banco, índices, etc...

Comment: então, antes com o Entity passando `.Include(i => i.IdEnvironmentNavigation).Include(i => i.IdServerTypeNavigation).Include(i => i.IdPlantNavigation).ToListAsync();` no `return` ele nem apresentava nada na tabela e ficava [desse jeito](https://prnt.sc/tttuwl),18 minutos carregando e mesmo assim nada, agora quando eu passava apenas 2 "Includes" EX: `.Include(i => i.IdEnvironmentNavigation).Include(i => i.IdServerTypeNavigation).ToListAsync();` ele demorava 0.58ms e apresentava só os 2 [imagem aqui](https://prnt.sc/tttyjj)

Comment: Comentei o using todo e deixei só o entity como recomendado acima [foto](https://prnt.sc/ttu7xa) porém ele continua consultando eternamente [print tabela](https://prnt.sc/ttuc5e)

Comment: Rovann teria alguma idéia do que eu poderia fazer ou estudar pra poder fazer isso?

Comment: tenta executar um request manualmente com o postman... pra ver se é na api também né... mas precisaria ver o que foi feito no banco, como está seu relacionamento etc...

Comment: Vou fazer isso agora. Vou ter que falar com o time porque não fui eu que modelei o banco sou estagiário to sofrendo hahah

Comment: Rovann meu nobre, pelo postman mandei um request do tipo GET e ele me retornou: Status: 200 OK, Time: 506ms, Size: 847 B

Comment: 500ms pode até ser demorado dependendo do cenário, mas aparentemente o problema não está na api...

Comment: Seria no front? também imaginei q n seria na API pq se n ele me retornaria erro no console do browser

Comment: To fazendo com o angular [codigo](https://prnt.sc/ttwlgt) aqui no meu service na parte `prop` eu to puxando os valores que estavam no `return await _context`

Comment: Aparentemente encontrei o erro, eu to fazendo a consulta no banco pelo GET porém não estou chamando nada do datatable no return, e sim verificando de outra forma (oq faz pesar minha api), aparentemente é esse o problema, agora preciso procurar como retornar esse datatable

Comment: como já disse acima, comente o bloco using todo... não use um `DataTable`...

Comment: Consegui resolver, vou postar a resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, depois de muita pesquisa e testes (com direito a umas pitadas de frustração) eu consegui resolver o problema :D vou postar a solução abaixo e ir explicando como cheguei até este resultado.

**Solução:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Server>>> GetServer()
{
    using (var context = new ITControlContext())
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT s.IdServer, s.IP, s.Name, s.Description, e.Name [Environment], t.Name [ServerType], p.Name [Plant], s.CreatedAt, s.UserInserted, s.UpdatedAt, s.UserUpdated FROM [ITControl].[dbo].[Server] s INNER JOIN[ITControl].[dbo].[Environment] e on s.IdEnvironment = e.IdEnvironment INNER JOIN[ITControl].[dbo].[ServerType] t on s.IdServerType = t.IdServerType INNER JOIN[ITControl].[dbo].[Plant] p on s.IdPlant = p.IdPlant";
            context.Database.OpenConnection();
            dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
        
        return Ok(dataTable);
    }          
}
```

Basicamente, o que eu fiz foi recuperar minha conexão com o banco dentro do `[HttpGet]` utilizando o seguinte bloco:

```
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT s.IdServer, s.IP, s.Name, s.Description, e.Name [Environment], t.Name [ServerType], p.Name [Plant], s.CreatedAt, s.UserInserted, s.UpdatedAt, s.UserUpdated FROM [ITControl].[dbo].[Server] s INNER JOIN[ITControl].[dbo].[Environment] e on s.IdEnvironment = e.IdEnvironment INNER JOIN[ITControl].[dbo].[ServerType] t on s.IdServerType = t.IdServerType INNER JOIN[ITControl].[dbo].[Plant] p on s.IdPlant = p.IdPlant";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
}
```

porém ao invés de retornar o dataTable que estava carregando esta consulta, eu ainda estava retornando o comando antigo (através de Includes, fazendo assim com que a implementação dessa conexão com o dataTable fosse "inútil" já que eu não estava consumindo-a). Outro erro também é que eu estava chamando o `System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();` dentro do próprio bloco de conexão, não conseguindo assim retornar ele. Então eu precisei primeiramente deixar essa instância do dataTable fora do bloco de conexão e ai sim retornando dentro do meu `return` passando ele com o método `Ok()`, ficando `Ok(dataTable)` e voilá, funcionou.

Até separei uma imagem comparativa com o tempo de resposta com o antes e o depois, vejam a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi possível sair de 34.4 segundos (isso que assim nem listava tudo oq eu precisava, porque se eu colocasse tudo ele sequer carregava [vejam](https://prnt.sc/tv28cf)) e consegui ir para 583ms listando todos os dados necessários.